# Which method is chosen in a polymorphism when calling a method available in the parent and the child class?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I don't understand why the `ab.m3()` method calls the function of the parent class and not the child. I thought maybe passing a new `Integer` to the method might call the method of the parent class because `Integer` is an `Object` so I tried it with an `int` but still it gave me the same result!

```
public class A {

    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("A.m1");
    }
    public void m2(){
        System.out.println("A.m2");
    }
    public void m3(Object x){
        System.out.println("A.m3");
    }
}

public class B extends A{

    public void m1(){
        System.out.println("B.m1");
    }
    public void m2(int x){
        System.out.println("B.m2");
    }
    public void m3(int x){
        System.out.println("B.m3");
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv){
        A aa = new A();
        A ab = new B();

        int num = 2;

        ab.m1();
        ab.m2();
        ab.m3(new Integer(2));
        ab.m3(num);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
B.m1
A.m2
A.m3
A.m3
```

Comment: `A.m3(Object) != B.m3(int)`, i.e. you are not overriding `m3` in `B`.

Comment: You should get in the habit of annotating methods that are overridden with `@Override`. Then the compiler can point out whether you've done it correctly (as is the case here).

Comment: Even if you were to add the overload `void m3(Integer x)` in `B` it wouldn't override `A.m3(Object)` as Java has covariant return type overrides but not contravariant parameter overrides. Best advice is to avoid overloading where possible.

Answer (score 3):

`B.m3` does not override `A.m3`, because the parameter lists are not compatible.

Because the only matching method in `A` is `A.m3`, and because there is no override in `B`, it is `A.m3` that will be called.

Comment: This.  Basically, Java always looks at the declared type when choosing which method to call.  Because all methods in Java are virtual, if it chooses A's `m1()` and the runtime type is B, it will instead call B's `m1()` because it overrides A's.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ab` reference is of type `A`.

When compiling `ab.m3(num);`, the compiler isn't looking at the object type. In general, it won't always know what the object type is. Instead, it's looking at the reference type. It cannot match `B.m3(int)`, because the reference type is not of type B.

So the compiler chooses the `A.m3(Object)` method, which could be overridden at runtime. But it's not, so the A implementation is called.